# dango-filter shows all projects; however, only the projects that the logged-in user has created should be displayed

Tags: django

as a beginner i have a problem with django. I programmed a django_filter. In views.py:

```
'''
class AufgabenView(LoginRequiredMixin, ListView):
    model = Aufgaben
    template_name = 'aufgaben/aufgaben.html'
    # object_list bekommt einen Namen
    context_object_name = 'aufgaben'
    #paginate_by = 2
    filterset_class = AufgabenFilter

    # nur datensätze anzeigen, für die der User berechtigt ist.
    def get_queryset(self):
        queryset = super().get_queryset().filter(ersteller=self.request.user)
        return queryset

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)

        context['filter'] = AufgabenFilter(self.request.GET, queryset=self.get_queryset())
        

        context['number_results'] = context['filter'].qs.count()
 
        return context
'''
```

Unfortunately, all projects are displayed. Also those created by other users. from models.py:

```
'''
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from home.models import Projekt
from datetime import datetime

STATUS = ((0, "erledigt"), (1, "offen"), (2, "nachverfolgen"), (3, "ruht"))

class Aufgaben(models.Model):
    datum = models.DateField(default=datetime.now)
    schlagwort = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True, blank=True)
    aufgabe = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    anmerkung = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
    frist = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)
    aufgabenstatus = models.IntegerField(choices=STATUS, default=1)
    erstellt_am = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    ersteller = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    projektbezug = models.ForeignKey(Projekt, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['projektbezug','datum']

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.aufgabe) + ' im Projekt: ' + str(self.projektbezug) '''
```

How can I filter the queryset so that only the authorized user's projects are visible?
Greetings Michael

Comment: Questions on StackOverflow should be written in English.

Comment: thanks, i changed the language.